# Magento ver. 1.9.0.1 - How to list all sub-categories in CMS Page?

Tags: category

I have a problem customizing a Magento page.

Categories (example):
Default Category (0)
 - Products (9)
   - High Bay (0)

In directory -> `public_html/app/design/frontend/template/default/template/page/list.phtml`

list.phtml (code below)

```
    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');  
            $_categories = $_category
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('level', 3)
            ->addAttributeToSelect("*");

            foreach ($_categories as $_category){
                //print_r($_category);
                //die(0);
                echo $_category->getThumbnail().'   ';
                echo $_category->getName().'   ';
            }
                ?>
```

Can I ask users here how do I retrieve and display an image and create a link to respective category products? I am getting only image name with no image display.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_category->getThumbnail() is give image path from media/catalog.

If you want full image then you need append Media catalog path in you image url

```
Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$_category->getThumbnail()
```

Full code:

```
<img src="<?php eccho Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$_category->getThumbnail()?>"  alt="<?php echo $_category->getName();?> "/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

I append but it does not show me the image, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: is $_category->getThumbnail() give any data?

Comment: Yes, I have uploaded a category image to test out the result.

It is returning a filename (ex. bulb.png)

Comment: Here you upload this.. Can you please give me screen shot

Comment: sorry,i want to screen of category at admin

Comment: Hi Amit, 

What do I need to upload? Can't see anything from you.

The output for $_category->getThumbnail() is only a image file name. (ex. bulb.png)

By the way, your code is right. It gives me the full path to the image, can I know how do I display the image and not the full path?
(eg. http://domain/media/catalog/category/ 

Million thanks for your assistance.

Comment: please checked bulb.png save at Your magento dir/media/catalog/category  or not?

Comment: Apologies, it is a basic mistake of mine.

I did not include the img tag. :'(